# Subject Subscription is triggered twice when I call .next() once in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs6, subject

i'm trying to create a reusable Modal component.
in a ModalService i have a Subject, and a method that that calls next() on the subject.
The ModalComponent subscribes to that subject, but whenever the method in the service is being called, the next function of the observer gets triggers twice.
Anyone know what causes this?

```
export class ModalService { 
  openModal = new Subject(); 

  constructor() { } 

  open(cmp) { 
     this.openModal.next(cmp); 
   } 
}
```

Modal Component:

```
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  component: ComponentRef<any>;

  @ViewChild('entry', { read: ViewContainerRef }) entry: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private modalService: ModalService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.modalService.openModal.subscribe(cmp => {

      // CALLD TWICE EVRY TIME THE SERVICE CALLS .next()
      console.log(cmp);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

It is not clear in your question where and how `open()` method is called. Is it the `open()` called twice or `subscribe()` triggered twice?

But if you want to share the last value with the subscribers you could use `shareReplay()` in `pipe()` like this:

```
export class ModalService { 
  openModalSubject = new Subject(); 
  openModal = this.openModalSubject.asObservable().pipe(shareReplay());
  constructor() { } 

  open(cmp) { 
     this.openModalSubject.next(cmp); 
   } 
}
```

**UPDATE**

And in your modal component, you need to `unsubscribe` from the observable when navigating from it. You can do it two ways.

First Way:

```
 modalSubscription: Subscription;

 ngOnInit() {
    this.modalSubscription = this.modalService.openModal.subscribe(cmp => {
      console.log(cmp);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.modalSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Second Way:

```
 unsubscribeSignal: Subject<void> = new Subject();

 ngOnInit() {
    this.modalSubscription = this.modalService.openModal
    .pipe(
       takeUntil(this.unsubscribeSignal.asObservable()),
    )
    .subscribe(cmp => {
      console.log(cmp);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.unsubscribeSignal.next();
  }
```

I prefer the second way mostly. This way, you can unsubscribe more than one observable at once.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The open method can be called from any component in the app that needs to trigger the Modal. i tried injecting this service to the AppComponent, and called modalService.open() once. The subscribe is triggerd twice for some reason.

Comment: I tried to explain the possible reason in the update section. Please have a look at. If you do not unsubscribe from observable and re-init modal component, it may trigger twice.

Comment: Btw, I suggest you to go into the source code of the modal service of this well-tested library (ngx-bootstrap: [Home Page](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals), [GitHub](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap)) to have a more generic point of view.

Comment: Had a similar issue and can confirm that unsubscribing onDestroy can fix this issue.  Also keep in mind when your subscriptions are being initiated, while onInit this will ( with default change detection ) will redraw your component if any of its properties are changed.   Consider using AfterViewInit for your subscriptions to avoid any unnecessary functions being called when manipulating component data.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to push all subscriptions in the array and unsubscribe it into the ngondestroy.

```
First import the Subscription from rxjs
     import { Subscription} from 'rxjs';
    
second create global property in component     
     subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
    
    
Third push all the subscribe in subscriptions property
    constructor(){
    this.subscriptions.push(this.Service.subject1.subscribe((result) => {
          console.log('subject1');
    
        }));
    
        this.subscriptions.push(this.dataService.subject2.subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('subject2')
    }
    
    
 Lastly unsubscribe it   
     ngOnDestroy() {
       
        this.subscriptions.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
    
    
      }
```