# How to unsubscribe from not initialized subscription in Angular

Tags: angular

I got following error:

**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined**

I have subscription not on ngOnInit and that's why I got this error, because my property that holding the subscription is not yet initialized, but what's the 'proper way' in such a situation.

Here is my code:

[image: img]

Comment: Check to see if the sub exist before unsubscribing. With an if statement.

Comment: You unsubscribing from an object that has not been initialized. Try to check if this.sub is defined before unsubscribing to it.

Comment: delcare a variable `isAlive = true;` then remove `sub` and  use takeWhile from rxJs: `this.authService.login(this.login.form.value).takeWhile(() => this.isAlive).subscribe(...); in the `onDestroy`: `this.isAlive = false;`

Comment: Assign the subscription to a variable and check if it is defined. Off topic: Do not use images to show the code.

Comment: Private sub: Subscription = new Subscription();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `takeUntil()` operator of `rxjs` with `pipe()` before subscribing to the observable.

```
 unsubscribeSignal: Subject<void> = new Subject();

 ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.observableToSubscribe
    .pipe(
       takeUntil(this.unsubscribeSignal.asObservable()),
    )
    .subscribe(result => {

      //Do some fancy stuff here

      console.log(result );
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.unsubscribeSignal.next();
  }
```

Another benefit of using `takeUntil` instead of manually unsubscribing the subscription is that you can use a single `Subject` to unsubscribe multiple subscriptions at once.

You can check out my another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53978917/1331040)

Comment: Thanks you, that works. I have one more question. What is the difference between your code and if I skip pipe, so just chain takeUntil after observableToSubscribe?

Comment: You're welcome. AFAIK, with the latest version of `RxJS` (v6.x), `takeUntil` becomes a pipeable operator and should be used only in `pipe` method.